# What is the striped thing on Jango's chin?

Tags: one-piece

Jango is an antagonist, who first appeared in episode 9, during the Syrup Village arc. What is the striped thing seen on his chin? (Encircled in the image below.)

[image: Striped thing on Jango's chin]

Answer (score 5):

According to Eiichiro Oda, the striped thing on Jango's chin is a leftover mushroom!

Before becoming a pirate, Jango was a wandering dancer. Business wasn't good, so all he did was sleep. He did not even take baths. Eventually, a striped fungus grew from his filthy chin. Jango was so hungry, he tried eating the cap of the mushroom, and found it disgusting! He gulped it down anyway, and after than he somehow gained the ability to hypnotize people. The trunk of the mushroom was left on his chin.

---

<sup>Source: One Piece SBS, Volume 6.</sup>